# Square connect API not returning item quantity

Tags: square

**How do I get inventory levels when listing catalog items?**

I'm using the Square Connect Node SDK https://www.npmjs.com/package/square-connect for an e-commerce project. I'm making requests using Node / Express JS to Square copying (with some small modification) the examples in the SDK documentation. I'm getting data back from Square, but I can't get the inventory levels for any of my products.

The only inventory data I see in the response from Square (when using this example code https://docs.connect.squareup.com/api/connect/v2#endpoint-listcatalog) is:

```
"location_overrides": [{
"location_id": "my-location-id",
"track_inventory": true,
"inventory_alert_type": "LOW_QUANTITY",
"inventory_alert_threshold": 15 }]
```

I thought I saw missing something, so I went back to the Square docs https://docs.connect.squareup.com/api/connect/v2 and searched on the page for "inventory," and the values listed above are the only thing that comes up.

**Things I've tried on the Square dashboard:**

1. Enabling / disabling inventory tracking
2. Setting an inventory level for multiple items
3. Enabling / disabling inventory level alerts

Any help or additional info on this would be greatly appreciated! I've been seeing similar questions where people are using the PHP SDK and getting the stock levels for products, so I know it's a supported feature. I just can't figure out what I'm doing wrong..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Currently the only way to list/adjust inventory in Square's APIs is to use Connect v1 (which the Node SDK supports). Please see our doc site for more information: https://docs.connect.squareup.com/api/connect/v1#navsection-inventory

Comment: I have a related follow up: using the V1 endpoint I'm able to list the inventory levels for my catalog items (thanks!), but it looks like the only data returned from the API is the item ID and it's stock level. Is there anyway to get the catalog data (item name, price, etc.) and the inventory levels in one call? Or do I need to make a subsequent call to fetch the inventory and build the full data set on my end?

Comment: Unfortunately you would need to do another call like you said. You would use the item ID that the inventory endpoint gives you to retrieve it from the catalog endpoint.